# Current in a RC circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, capacitance

In order to find current in an RC circuit, resistance of only the resistor is considered i.e. $I_\text{resistor} = V_\text{resistor} / R$. Why is the reactance of the capacitor not considered? The frequency of the ac signal has an affect in circuit with a capacitor. Why is that effect is not considered while calculating current in a RC circuit?

Comment: *"In order to find current in RC circuit, resistance of only resistor is considered"* - This isn't true.

Comment: Looking closely at what you wrote, I see that it is can be true depending on how the circuit is wired, and what you mean by "current in RC circuit".  But it is not particularly useful.  The current in the resistor is indeed Voltage(resistor)/Resistance(resistor), but this may not be "current in RC circuit".

Comment: Do you mean an RC series connected to a DC source?  The voltage across the resistor is affected by the voltage across the capacitor. And you have the concept backwards. The capacitive reactance is an effect built from the basic behavior of the capacitor, $Q=CV_C$.

Answer (score 0):

No.both are considered to find the current 
let the alternating voltage varies in sinusoidal form
the current is given by the voltage equation (sinusoidal form with phase change as there is phase difference between the impedance vector and the resistance) divided by impedance(which involves both resistance and capacitive reactance.

Answer (score 0):

Capacitive reactance is a description of behaviour of capacitor in AC circuits, where current oscillates harmonically and all transient phenomena in the circuit died away long time ago.

In case we study discharge of the capacitor through a resistor, there is no AC current, just a transient discharge. The discharge requires more detailed description in terms of differential equation in time, the concept of impedance or reactance is not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Because unlike resistor, capacitor is time dependent and that makes it useful for memory devices, controlling and logic circuits. Transistors used in IC for logic are badically transistors with three electrode. So capicatance offer time dependent resistance, once it's charged it blocks flow of current, infinite resistance. So initially when it is uncharged, it show zero resistance so that more current quickly charge it.

In discharging of a capacitor, it acts like a source. So technically it need not have any resistance and all current should drawn by load or resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Resistance is the opposition to the current while the reactance of inductor and capacitor is the opposition to the change in current.